# Объект проходит сквозь другие

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity3d-editor

Движение объекта осуществляется через:

```
if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
    transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x+1,
                                     transform.position.y,
                                     transform.position.z)
```

На нем висит колайдер и ригибоди.

Comment: `rigidBody.isKinematic = false`?

Answer (score 3):

Во-первых, как правильно заметили в комментарии, проверьте, что у `rigitbody.isKinematic` имеет значение `false`.

Во-вторых, вы используете для столкновений физику, а перемещаете объект с помощью изменения `transform.position`, что не совсем корректно и не согласуется с просчетом физики. Попробуйте либо искать коллизии с помощью [Raycast](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html), либо двигать объект с помощью физики, например [Rigitbody.AddForce](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddForce.html).

В третьих, проверьте, что слои на которых находятся объекты с физикой настроены правильно. Об этом можно почитать [здесь](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/LayerBasedCollision.html).